# use environment variables in haproxy

Tags: variables, acl, environment, haproxy

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I am trying to configure HAProxy to use an environment variable (from the operating system) as part of an acl statement.
So if the environment variable is set to true when HAProxy is started or reloaded then access is granted.  If the environment variable is set to false then I would just want the NOSVR error to be generated.

I know that if I also put in a rule that says
use_backend ftp1-srv unless accessFtp then the request goes through OK which seems to indicate that the acl section is is not working.

I have found very little in my searches that show how to use environment variables in this way just that you should be able to do a sample fetch from the internal state with env(name)

This is what I have tried so far:

```
frontend ftp-in
    bind *:2200
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    log /dev/log local1 debug
    acl accessFtp env(accessFTP) eq true
    use_backend ftp1-srv if accessFtp
backend ftp1-srv
    balance source
    option tcplog
    server ftp1 127.0.0.1:21
```

Answer (score 3):

```
acl accessFtp env(accessFTP) eq true
```

This probably doesn't work because `eq` is an integer equality comparison operator, `env()` returns a string and `true` is... okay, I'm not sure how `true` would be typed, in an integer comparison against a string, but either way, the result will not be what you expect.

Use an explicit string comparison if the environment variable contains the literal string `true`.

```
acl accessFtp env(accessFTP) -m str true
```

Or, you should be able to use the "a value was found" match test if you only want to test that the environment variable has been set to anything.  This should be false if the value is not set at all.

```
acl accessFtp env(accessFTP) -m found
```

You can also tidy up your config by removing the named acl and replacing it with an anonymous one.

```
use_backend ftp1-srv if accessFtp if { env(accessFTP) -m str true }
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with environment variables when running as a service and solved it by setting them from  `/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service`. I'm not sure if it helps in your case.

For more details see [this question](https://serverfault.com/a/841305/384703) or that file.